# Ground filter package for tilt laser that works under Hydro?

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro, laser-filters, pr2, laser-assembler

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am using the [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) package to generate a point cloud from the scans of a tilting Hokuyo laser scanner. However, I am struggeling to find an existing ROS package to filter out the reflections of the ground plane that is available/compiles under ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04.

I am aware that there are several established means of accomplishing this task. Unfortunately, none of the ones I came across seems to work under Hydro. This is what I have been looking at:

[laser_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters) is available on Hydro, but does not come with a ground filter plugin by default. Does anyone know of a ground filter plugin that works on Hydro?

The latest version of [pr2_navigation_perception](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_navigation_perception) is for Groovy only and has not been migrated to Hydro. It uses the [semantic_point_annotator](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_navigation/tree/groovy-devel/semantic_point_annotator), the launch file is [ground_plane.xml](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/trunk/applications/2dnav_pr2_app/2dnav_pr2/config/ground_plane.xml?rev=23911). So far, I have  successfully catkinized it but failed to compile it due to pcl header issues

[ua-ros-pkg](https://code.google.com/p/ua-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Farrg%2Fua_vision%2Fbackground_filters%2Fsrc%253Fstate%253Dclosed) is also outdated (rosbuild/Groovy). I catkinzed it, but also no luck after several hours of trying to get it compile on hydro.

Another related post can be found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/37126/pr2-sees-ghost-obstacles-in-tilting-laser/).

As this is such a common task, I am reaching out to the community hoping that there is a solution out there.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144296/ground-filter-package-for-tilt-laser-that-works-under-hydro?/) by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 399 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can't find an existing package, you could write a quick node that uses the PCL passthrough filter (http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php). You would first transform the pointcloud into a frame like base_link or base_footprint, and then cut out anything with a z < 0.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0